# Python Get Words(Lines) From String Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string value with multiple lines (exact data is long and complex, word length for each are different, line order may change, but I know only `wordx:` values (word1, word4, word7,...) for searching, data is simplified here):

```
word1: word2 word3 word10 word11 word12
word4: word5 word6 word13 word14 word15
word7: word8 word9 word16
word0: word1 word1 word19 word20 word21 word22
.
.
.
word100: word101 . . .
```

**Update:** How `word5 word6 word13 word14 word15` could be get as a single string by using Python?
Python3.8.7.

Comment: are you going for something like `print('the dogs barked'.split().count('dogs'))` ?

Comment: Your example doesn't look like a string.  Is this your string: "word1: word2 word3\nword4: word5 word6\nword7: word8 word9"?  Or is it a text file, entries in a dictionary, or a list of lists.  The answer affects how you would access a particular element.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = “word1: word2 word3 word4: word5 word6 word7: word8 word9”
y = x.split()
print(y[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'word1: word2 word3 word10 word11 word12\nword4: word5 word6 word13 word14 word15\nword7: word8 word9 word16\nword0: word1 word1 word19 word20 word21 word22'
#since you have a file with multiple lines there will be \n once it gets read

line_you_need = s.split("\n")[1] 
#your word is present in second line index value of which in list is 1 here you will get your desired line which is 'word4: word5 word6'

string_you_need= line_you_need.split(":")[1].strip()
#similarly here you will get your desired string.

print (string_you_need)
```

One liner for the same is

```
string_you_need= s.split("\n")[1].split(":")[1].strip()
```

Comment: Your answer works partially for my problem. I have updated the question. How ```word5 word6 word13 word14 word15``` could be get as a single string?

Comment: I have made changes as per your need